# Rsyslog filter on machine hostname and not previous rsyslog server

Tags: linux, rsyslog

I have a requirement to forward logs from hostname X to IP 1.1.1.1. However, the feed that is being received is from another Rsyslog server Y. Due to this, the existing condition is not working as it is looking for server Y's hostname instead of X. Can you please suggest how to fix this and provide the correct syntax?

Existing condition:

if $hostname == 'X' then @@1.1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to filter the logs according to the fromhost property.

https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/configuration/properties.html

[...]
fromhost
hostname of the system the message was received from (in a relay chain, this is the system immediately in front of us and not necessarily the original sender). This is a DNS-resolved name, except if that is not possible or DNS resolution has been disabled.
[...]